# How to findViewById a view that is not in the main Activity ?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two xml files :

- activity_main.xml (which is the layout for the main activity)
- separate.xml (which contains a view, for instance a customized
  button)

> separate.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>
>      <Button
>         android:id="@+id/myButton"
>         android:layout_width="50dp"
>         android:layout_height="50dp"
>         android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
>         android:elevation="0dp"
>         android:onClick="onMyButtonClicked"/>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Now, if I want to add this layout inside a view in my main activity, I have to inflate first and then push the inflated view inside a parent layout.

```
View buttonLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.separate, null);
parentLayout.addView(buttonLayout);
```

But what I want to do is

```
parentLayout.addView(findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout));
```

I know it's just about the same but I'd like to be able to do that for a personal organisation. In other words, is it possible to separate views in different files and register them (using their layout's id) in the main activity so we can accesss them using `findViewById` ?

ps : i tried to use the context property but nothing changed. Maybe we can put the views in activity_main and hide them from the screen just for the purpose ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, exactly. If `findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout)` returns a (non-null) `View`, then that `View` is already added to the `View` hierarchy, and that `parentLayout.addView()` call will throw an `IllegalStateException`, since that `View` already has a parent.

Comment: May be override `findViewById` in your `Activity` and make it inflate from the layout id and then retrun the `View`?

Comment: @MikeM. `findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout)` returns a (null) View, that's my point. it is null because the View is in another xml file and is not related to the main Activity, i want to find a way to tell the main Activity "this xml file belongs to you too" without explicitly inflate it.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm saying. If it returns a non-null `View`, that `View` is already added, so `parentLayout.addView()` will still crash. As I said, it's not clear what you're really trying to do. A `View` specified in layout XML doesn't exist until it's inflated, and your `Activity`'s `findViewById()` won't find it until it's added to its hierarchy. Are you looking for the `<include>` tag, to add that other layout inside `activity_main`? Using that, you won't have to explicitly inflate the other layout. It'll happen when you call `setContentView()`.

Comment: Or, from the last sentence in your post, maybe you want a [`ViewStub`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)?

Comment: @MikeM. Ok I didn't mention but parentLayout is not the main activity, it's another View inside the main activity (like a sub-layout). I wanted to explicitly tell the main activity to inflate and add a layout (separate.xml) to its hierarchy, but i think now I understand, findViewById is searching for the visible elements of a layout ? in that case ViewStub seems to be the widget that I need. thanks

Comment: you can add view to your main activity or you can also use include in xml to add that layout and then you can use that id in your main activity class